# Abel Equation of Second Kind

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am interested in solving an Abel equation of the second kind.([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3126191/non-exact-differential-equation))

I have come across few papers proposing methods to go about this and they rely heavily on guessing the functional form. As it is a challenging task, I am planning to attack a different question: existence and uniqueness of solution. Are there theorems\literature which can help me proving\disproving uniqueness of the solution conditional on its existence?

Thank you very much.